# How to query dissimilar tables with no direct relation and combine ambiguous columns

Tags: mysql, sql

## *THIS QUESTION HAS BEEN EDITED AFTER FEEDBACK FROM ORIGINAL QUESTION RESPONDER*

I have a complex MySQL problem where I need to query across dissimilar tables that don't necessarily have anything to join to. **I'm dealing with a third-party system, so I can't make any changes to the structure of the database**.

I'm grossly oversimplifying the question for the sake of brevity, but the simplest way I can think to explain it is: I need to get a list of students and their primary activity. The students are contained in a single table, but the problem is that the activity they are in is referenced through other tables which only have a rough relationship. Each building has (2) tables of custom field information. "XX_CUSTOMFIELDNAMES" has the name of the custom field, and "XX_CUSTOMFIELDVALUES" contains the related value. In this case, the custom field name is "Activity"

**Tables and Sample Data**:

```
======================================
| STUDENTS                           |
======================================
| studentID | studentName | building | 
--------------------------------------
| 101       | Bob         | HS       |
| 102       | Amy         | MS       |
| 103       | Jim         | ES       |
| 104       | Andy        | HS       |
--------------------------------------

=======================         ====================================
| HS_CUSTOMFIELDNAMES |         |      HS_CUSTOMFIELDVALUES        |
=======================         ====================================
| fieldID | fieldname |         | fieldID | studentID | fieldvalue |
-----------------------         ------------------------------------
| 48      | Activity  |         | 48      | 101       | Football   |
| 49      | Health    |         | 49      | 101       | Asthma     |
-----------------------         ------------------------------------

=======================         ====================================
| MS_CUSTOMFIELDNAMES |         |      MS_CUSTOMFIELDVALUES        |
=======================         ====================================
| fieldID | fieldname |         | fieldID | studentID | fieldvalue |
-----------------------         ------------------------------------
| 44      | Activity  |         | 44      | 102       | Track      | 
-----------------------         ------------------------------------

=======================         ====================================
| ES_CUSTOMFIELDNAMES |         |      ES_CUSTOMFIELDVALUES        |
=======================         ====================================
| fieldID | fieldname |         | fieldID | studentID | fieldvalue |
-----------------------         ------------------------------------
| 43      | Activity  |         | 43      | 103       | Band       |
| 42      | Teacher   |         | 42      | 103       | Mr. Smith  |
-----------------------         ------------------------------------
```

**An Example**:

To determine which activity `Bob` is in, we have to look at his building `HS` and student ID `101`. Since his building is `HS`, we have to look at the `HS-CUSTOMFIELDNAMES` table to find the field name `Activity` and grab the `fieldID` of `48`. We then have to look at the `HS_CUSTOMFIELDVALUES` table to find the `fieldID` of `48` and Bob's student ID of `101`. We can then see that Bob is in Football and has a `health` value of `asthma`. However, we only want to query the `Activity` or lack thereof.

I have the following query which doesn't get the NULL activity value and doesn't combine the 'Activity' field as you can see (*because otherwise I get an 'ambiguous column name' error*). In addition, I skipped the "ES" building to make the query shorter for here.

```
SELECT
  s.studentID, s.studentName, s.building, COALESCE(HS.fieldvalue, MS.fieldvalue, ES.fieldvalue) AS 'Activity'
FROM
  students s
LEFT JOIN
  HS_CUSTOMFIELDVALUES HS
  ON
    s.studentID = HS.studentID 
LEFT JOIN
  HS_CUSTOMFIELDNAMES AS HSF
  ON HSF.fieldID = HS.fieldID AND HSF.fieldname = 'Activity'
LEFT JOIN
  MS_CUSTOMFIELDVALUES MS
  ON
    s.studentID = MS.studentID 
LEFT JOIN
  MS_CUSTOMFIELDNAMES AS MSF
  ON MSF.fieldID = MS.fieldID AND MSF.fieldname = 'Activity'
LEFT JOIN
  ES_CUSTOMFIELDVALUES ES
  ON
    s.studentID = ES.studentID 
LEFT JOIN
  ES_CUSTOMFIELDNAMES AS ESF
  ON ESF.fieldID = ES.fieldID AND ESF.fieldname = 'Activity'
```

**Actual Query Result**:

```
==================================================
| studentID | studentName | building | Activity  |
--------------------------------------------------
| 101       | Bob         | HS       | Asthma    |    
| 101       | Bob         | HS       | Football  |
| 102       | Amy         | MS       | Track     |
| 103       | Jim         | ES       | Band      |
| 103       | Jim         | ES       | Mr. Smith |
| 104       | Andy        | HS       |           |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Since neither the first and fifth records are an `Activity`, I need to not return those results so that the output looks like the following:

**Desired Query Result**:

```
=================================================
| studentID | studentName | building | activity |
-------------------------------------------------
| 101       | Bob         | HS       | Football |
| 102       | Amy         | MS       | Track    |
| 103       | Jim         | ES       | Band     |
| 104       | Andy        | HS       |          |
-------------------------------------------------
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b747ce/1/0

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ugh, what a horrible design. Dynamic information should not be in table names, it should be in table data.

Comment: When you "simplify", it would be nice if you didn't change all the table and column names from the ones you use in your query.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the "simplification" query to reflect the example tables rather than the real world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use subqueries to get just the activities from each pair of tables. Then `LEFT JOIN` each of these queries with the `students` table, and use `COALESCE()` to specify the priority.

```
SELECT
  s.studentID, s.studentName, s.building, COALESCE(HS.fieldvalue, MS.fieldvalue, ES.fieldvalue) AS 'Activity'
FROM
  students s
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT HS.studentID, HS.fieldvalue
 FROM 
  HS_CUSTOMFIELDVALUES HS
 JOIN
  HS_CUSTOMFIELDNAMES AS HSF
  ON HSF.fieldID = HS.fieldID
 WHERE HSF.fieldname = 'Activity') AS HS
 ON S.studentID = HS.studentID
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT MS.studentID, MS.fieldvalue
 FROM 
  MS_CUSTOMFIELDVALUES MS
 JOIN
  MS_CUSTOMFIELDNAMES AS MSF
  ON MSF.fieldID = MS.fieldID
 WHERE MSF.fieldname = 'Activity') AS MS
 ON S.studentID = MS.studentID
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT ES.studentID, ES.fieldvalue
 FROM 
  ES_CUSTOMFIELDVALUES ES
 JOIN
  ES_CUSTOMFIELDNAMES AS ESF
  ON ESF.fieldID = ES.fieldID
 WHERE ESF.fieldname = 'Activity') AS ES
 ON S.studentID = ES.studentID
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b747ce/3)

Comment: Thank you. This is pretty close, but I'm not getting results where the `Activity` is `NULL` (see "Andy" in the example), and it's still splitting the `Activity` column in the final result as two different columns (even though they have the same name of `Activity'.

Comment: I've combined them using `COALESCE()`

Comment: Thanks, COALESCE works. Any idea regarding the appropriate method to make sure I get results where the Activity is NULL (see "Andy" in the example)

Comment: I've updated the answer. Move the field name checks into the `ON` clause.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. The problem I have yet is that I'm getting results for other custom fields that are not `Activity`. I updated the question above based on your last edits and put the SQL query there to create the sample data if that would help clarify the problem.  Thanks again, Beems.

Comment: Can you create a sqlfiddle with sample data so I can try to debug it?

Comment: Sure thing, I should have thought to do that in the first place. Here's the link: sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b747ce/1/0

Comment: Thanks, this works exactly as expected. I marked as answered.